# AttributeError: module '_tkinter' has no attribute 'Frame'

Tags: python, tkinter, window, frame

im trying to run a simple window using some copied code from a tutorial. i get an error as described in title, the main class is not getting a recognized reference to my library tkinter.. whats wrong with the code?? my file name is buzz.py (i saw some similar problems where the problem was in the name of the file of the code..

```
     import _tkinter as tk
        from _tkinter import *
        class Example(tk.Frame):
            def __init__(self, parent):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            # create a prompt, an input box, an output label,
            # and a button to do the computation
            self.prompt = tk.Label(self, text="Enter a number:", anchor="w")
            self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
            self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.calculate)
            self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")

            # lay the widgets out on the screen.
            self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
            self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
            self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
            self.submit.pack(side="right")

        def calculate(self):
            # get the value from the input widget, convert
            # it to an int, and do a calculation
            try:
                i = int(self.entry.get())
                result = "%s*2=%s" % (i, i*2)
            except ValueError:
                result = "Please enter digits only"

            # set the output widget to have our result
            self.output.configure(text=result)

    # if this is run as a program (versus being imported),
    # create a root window and an instance of our example,
    # then start the event loop

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            root = tk.Tk()
            Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
            root.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it should be `tkinter` without `_` - `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: your code has wrong indentations - but indentations are very important in Python.

Comment: Instead of importing everything with `from _tkinter import *` try to import the classes you use from the modules individually. That way you can better pinpoint any missing import.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Python 3` then you need `tkinter` without `_`.

In `Python 2` you would need `Tkinter` with upper `T` but also without `_`.

Very imporatant are also indentations.

---

I assume you use Python 3 so you can also use

```
super().__init__(...)
```

instead of

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, ...)
```

See also [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  - `import *` is not preferred.

---

This code works for me

```
import tkinter as tk # Python 3
# from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.prompt = tk.Label(self, text="Enter a number:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.calculate)
        self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")

        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="right")

    def calculate(self):
        try:
            i = int(self.entry.get())
            result = "%s*2=%s" % (i, i*2)
        except ValueError:
            result = "Please enter digits only"

        self.output.configure(text=result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```